# How exactly can someone prove they were the creator of an NFT?

Tags: nft

On Etherium.org it states with regard to NFTs...
https://ethereum.org/en/nft/

> You can easily prove you're the creator.

How exactly can someone prove they were the creator of an NFT?

I am not concerned with the real world identity of the creator.  Only that someone with a certain wallet address (whoever they may be) was the actual creator.

I am not concerned with the case where someone else claims to be the creator of something I made.  But rather the opposite case of someone else claiming I made something that they actually made.

Comment: Blockchain explorers like etherscan.io show who sent the transaction that created the smart contract that contains the NFT. A signed message could be used as proof that someone owns that account.

Comment: @pwagner Thanks that puts me on the right path to a full answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to etherium.org

> All smart contracts and state changes on the Ethereum blockchain are executed by transactions.

https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/ethereum-stack/

Therefore the creation of the NFT must be the result of a transaction.

Additionally

> Transactions are cryptographically signed instructions from accounts.

They also define the signature as...

> signature – the identifier of the sender. This is generated when the
> sender's private key signs the transaction and confirms the sender has
> authorised this transaction

https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/transactions/

Since all transactions are signed by the sender, the transaction that created the NFT will have been signed by the sender of the transaction.

Since the NFT is created as a result of the transaction.  The NFT's creator is the sender of the transaction.  And we can verify who that is based on the signature attached to the transaction.

A block chain explorer like http://etherscan.io can be used to inspect the blockchain data.